Setting todays date as the name of the most recently added sheet in Google Sheets
I'm importing a spreadsheet and want to rename the tab to todays date.
I've tried this script but it targets a particular tab (the second one in this case) but I want to target the most recently added.
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tz = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MMM dd - yyyy');
  sheets[1]
  .setName(date);


Sheets do not have metadata that helps to identify which sheet was the most recently added. As sheets might be inserted between other sheets, it's not reliable to assume that the last sheet has been added most recently.
You might use a script that renames the active sheet or iterate over all the sheets to find something that could tell that the sheet was the last recently added, i.e., the default sheet name for spreadsheets created using English as the primary language starts with a Sheet followed by a number.

@Tanaike's Workaround
The script below is adapted from the script in @Tanaike's 2020-05-23 answer on this site.
The solution provides a workaround to retrieve a newly added or removed sheet's name because the OnChange trigger doesn't include that information and retrieving the active sheet's name always defaults to the sheet at index 0.
@Tanaike's workaround saves all the sheet names using the Properties Service and then, when a change type is detected that's either INSERT_GRID or REMOVE_GRID, it compares the current list to the saved list to identify the affected sheet.
Installation

As noted in @Tanaike's answer, you should close and reopen your spreadsheet after saving the script in order to trigger an initial onOpen execution of the function saveCurrentSheets.
You will need to install an OnChange event trigger pointing to the function newTab.

Script
function saveCurrentSheets(prop, spreadsheet) {
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets().reduce((o, s) => Object.assign(o, {[s.getSheetName()]: true}), {});
  prop.setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(sheets));
}

function onOpen(e) {
  saveCurrentSheets(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(), e.source);
}

function newTab(e) {
  if (e.changeType === "INSERT_GRID") {
    const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    const oldSheets = prop.getProperty("sheets");
    if (!oldSheets) {
      saveCurrentSheets(prop, e.source);
      return;
    }
    const oldSheetsObj = JSON.parse(prop.getProperty("sheets"));
    const addedSheet = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => !oldSheetsObj[s.getSheetName()])[0];
    const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MMM dd - yyyy (HH.mm.ss)');
    try {
      addedSheet.setName(date.substring(0, date.length-11));   
    }
    catch(err) {
      addedSheet.setName(date);
      console.log(err);
    }
    saveCurrentSheets(prop, e.source);
  } else if (e.changeType === "REMOVE_GRID") {
    saveCurrentSheets(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(), e.source);
  }
}

My Changes
This is fundamentally the same script as shared by @Tanaike with some small changes:

The function log was renamed to newTab to better reflect the changed behavior.

The script uses addedSheet, to identify the sheet to rename with the current date with your preferred formatting or a variation that also includes time if there's already a sheet named after the current date (two sheets can't share the same name).




Thanks for this. Since posting the question I actually resolved the problem myself. Part of my macro was to move the sheet into position 1. I simply moved the part which renamed the tab to todays date below this and it worked a treat. Hopefully your solution will help someone else with a similar issue. Thanks again.

I assume your approach relies on the fact that the new sheet is always inserted in the same position. For example, after the first or last sheet. @Tanaike's solution is more reliable as it isn't concerned with the position of the new sheet, and can be adapted to also move that new sheet into whatever position you want.

Yes, it always gets moved to the same position so I don't need that extra complexity. Thanks for you help.
